# How do I debug a full screen DirectX9 application from Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 without problems?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, directx

Well I want to debug my .dll which gets loaded into the process, and it's crashing somewhere. I tried to log which line gets executed last to a file but that din't help much.

Now, when I attach the debugger and the application crashes, MSVC debug freezes the proccess, making it impossible to alt tab to any other window and I'm stuck at a black screen with only Task Manager working. I tried shutting down the applications process, but it's impossible, then I had to shut down visual Studio - left without any clue what could cause the crash.

How can I effectively and without problems debug in this situation?

(remote debugging is not an option, I have no second machine at disposal, and I have no second screen too)

Comment: Have you tried recreating this bug in windowed mode? If it does not happen in windowed mode, you can probably assume it is something to do with the way you are going full screen. It will also mean that if it does still crash, you should be able to swap to VS with ease

Comment: the application has no options (no working shortcuts etc) for windowed mode and my DLL does work when I comment out a few totally unrelated to directx lines of code, and those few lines expand to a few thousand.. (in functions)

Comment: well, if you comment out those line and it works, I am going to assume it is something to do with what ever those few lines do. - captain obvious

Comment: Suggestion for a workaround: If you let it crash outside the IDE, does window error reporting kick in? In that case, grab the .mdmp file from %temp% while the dialog is open, kill everything, restart visual studio and checkout the .mdmp contents. It will provide you with the exception breakpoint (callstack, etc) without the full screen.

Comment: Loading another DLL, however the crash position is unknown because the debug in logfiles give me the 'answer' that the dll's loaded succesfully. so I can't know what crashes

Comment: If Windows Error Reporting doesn't work, just use ProcDump (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) with -e.

Comment: Paul-Jan yes error reporting does kick in but it tells that the error is in KERNELBASE.dll, anyway will try it

Comment: Locate a second monitor. Borrow one from a coworker, connect your TV or ask your neighbor or whatever else you can think of. That's really the only sane way to debug a fullscreen app. Otherwise, stick with lots and lots of logging. And of course, the crash dump

Comment: @GamErix: the minidump file contains a complete s tack trace, not just the name of the faulting DLL

Comment: Alternatively, use another computer and attach using the remote debugger.

Comment: Alternatively, construct a VM, run your app in the VM and remote debug it. 1 screen, effectively multiple computers unless your app is tied to having 3D graphics (some are). One system can do it, if it has enough power. If you want the VM to run Windows 7 64-bit, I suggest using Virtual Box.

Comment: well thanks for all the suggestions, I debugged the problem succesfully :) anyone places an answer? however how I did it: use DXWND (a freeware directx windower program) to force the program to windowed mode.